# Error when modifying classic Azure vnet

Tags: networking, powershell, azure, azure-networking

I'm trying to connect a classic Azure vnet to a new RM vnet. The end goal is to decommission the classic vnet, but I need to connect the two so I can get active directory servers going on the new vnet.

Anyway - I've used the classic CLI to download the config for the classic vnet, which looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NetworkConfiguration xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2011/07/NetworkConfiguration">
  <VirtualNetworkConfiguration>
    <Dns>
      <DnsServers>
        <DnsServer name="dc2" IPAddress="10.0.0.13" />
        <DnsServer name="dc3" IPAddress="10.0.0.12" />
      </DnsServers>
    </Dns>
    <VirtualNetworkSites>
      <VirtualNetworkSite name="PmdAzure" Location="East US">
        <AddressSpace>
          <AddressPrefix>10.0.0.0/24</AddressPrefix>
          <AddressPrefix>10.0.1.0/24</AddressPrefix>
        </AddressSpace>
        <Subnets>
          <Subnet name="dc">
            <AddressPrefix>10.0.0.9/29</AddressPrefix>
          </Subnet>
          <Subnet name="App">
            <AddressPrefix>10.0.0.16/28</AddressPrefix>
          </Subnet>
          <Subnet name="Api">
            <AddressPrefix>10.0.0.32/28</AddressPrefix>
          </Subnet>
          <Subnet name="Office">
            <AddressPrefix>10.0.1.0/24</AddressPrefix>
          </Subnet>
          <Subnet name="GatewaySubnet">
            <AddressPrefix>10.0.0.0/29</AddressPrefix>
          </Subnet>
        </Subnets>
        <DnsServersRef>
          <DnsServerRef name="dc3" />
          <DnsServerRef name="dc2" />
        </DnsServersRef>
      </VirtualNetworkSite>
    </VirtualNetworkSites>
  </VirtualNetworkConfiguration>
</NetworkConfiguration>
```

I then added the following to it:

```
 <LocalNetworkSites>
      <LocalNetworkSite name="RmVnetLocal">
        <AddressSpace>
          <AddressPrefix>10.1.4.0/24</AddressPrefix>
        </AddressSpace>
        <VPNGatewayAddress>removed</VPNGatewayAddress>
      </LocalNetworkSite>
    </LocalNetworkSites>

    <Gateway>
      <ConnectionsToLocalNetwork>
        <LocalNetworkSiteRef name="RmVnetLocal">
          <Connection type="IPsec" />
        </LocalNetworkSiteRef>
      </ConnectionsToLocalNetwork>
    </Gateway>
```

I then upload the config with *Set-AzureVNetConfig -ConfigurationPath xxx*, but the following error gets returned:

```
Set-AzureVNetConfig : BadRequest : The address 10.0.0.12 is reserved by the platform and cannot be used.
At line:1 char:1
```

I've tried to comment out the DNS servers, still the same error. Googling this error doesn't return anything of use, and I can't find any mention of it in any Azure documentation. Any suggestions?

Thanks much

Comment: Why are you taking this route, you can just use vnet peering to connect the two. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/create-peering-different-deployment-models

Comment: I didn't realize that was an option. Seems to work great, thank you